# How to get more than 200 data from a data store

Tags: rally

I would like to link TestCase TestFolder and TestSet.
To do so I start 2 WsapiDataStore queries one on TestFolder and one on TestSet.
Then I parse the data and get the matching TestCase.
Unfortunatly I have not found the way to get more than 200 elements for each queries or to
index the starting index of the queries.
The code I use for a WsapiDataStore query is

```
_GetTestSetStore : function(TestFolder, container) {
var TestSet_Store = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
    model : 'TestSet',
    fetch : [ 'FormattedID', 'TestSet' ],
    pageSize : PageSize,
    autoLoad : true,
        listeners : {
        load : function(TestSet_Store, TestSet_Data, success) {
            if (success) {
                container._CleanStore(TestSet_Store, TestSet_Data, TestFolder, container);
            } else {
                    alert('TestSet store query failed');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

},
Could you help please

Answer (score 0):

[Rally.data.wsapi.Store](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.wsapi.Store-cfg-limit) has a config property limit.

You may set limit to `Infinity`, no quotes.

limit : Number
The total number or records to retrieve with the initial load Defaults to one page worth. To retrieve all records specify `Infinity`

Comment: Make sure to capitalize "Infinity" as "infinity" will be undefined.